# very simple for loop very strange resault

Tags: objective-c

i know, its the most simple thing to do , but its not working !

i have this :

```
static float px=50;
static float py=40;

   for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
       for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       { 
           pixels[i]=CGPointMake( px+(i*32),   py+(j*32)   ); 
       }

    }



  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
         NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(pixels[i]));
```

it seems that the j is get a garbage values.
i get the first 10 points with **good** point.x values , and **strange** point.y values,that is not incremeant.

Comment: where and how is the `pixels` array defined?

Comment: CGPoint pixels[100]; right before the loop. why do i get garbage y values ??

Comment: just did: pixels[i+(j*10)]=CGPointMake( px+(i*32),   py+(j*32)   );  and the y values are ok. its strange, because i havnt change the y values...

Answer (score 2):

You're only indexing `pixels` by `i` so you write the same `pixels` entries for every `j`/row.

You don't give the declaration for `pixels` but I'm guessing you want something like `pixels[i + j*10]`.

Answer (score 1):

Valid is only last loop **j**, and the result is the same how in this case:

```
//for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
j=9;
{
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   { 
       pixels[i]=CGPointMake( px+(i*32),   py+(j*32)   ); 
   }

}
```

as I think, you need array of pixels:

```
CGPoint pixels[10][10];
```

and in the loop:

```
pixels[i][j]=CGPointMake( px+(i*32),   py+(j*32)   );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your pixels array only has 10 indexes ever being accessed, because the index i only goes from 0 to 9, independently of j.
So, index[10] and above will be nonsense because they are never written to.